How to implement a concurrency-safe static variable in Swift 6?
I'm working on a Swift 6 project and need to manage a static variable that stores network responses. The current implementation isn't concurrency-safe because multiple threads can access and modify the shared state, leading to race conditions. Previously this code worked on Swift 4.
extension NetworkRequestHandler {
// Basic static variable with concurrency issues
static private var cachedResponses: [NetworkResponse] = []

// Adding a response
static func addResponse(_ response: NetworkResponse) {
    cachedResponses.append(response)
}

// Removing all responses
static func clearResponses() {
    cachedResponses.removeAll()
}
}


private extension NetworkRequestHandler {
    // Helper function to retrieve the response for a specific request
    static func response(for request: URLRequest) -> NetworkResponse? {
        return cachedResponses.first { $0.url == request.url }
    }
}

So basically the problem is in this part of code static private var cachedResponses: [NetworkResponse] = [] with error - Static property 'cachedResponses' is not concurrency-safe because it is nonisolated global shared mutable state

While it is completely valid to make code concurrency-safe, I fear your use case, specifically the function that takes a request and  reads from the response cache, defeats the purpose of HTTP - a specification and standard. A request contains a URL, and this URL represents the location of a resource. So, when fetching a resource with a URL, you should adhere the to rules of HTTP. You might be interested in reading this: https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9111.html  Please note also, that URLSession already can use a cache - it might solve your problem. ;)

Look's like you just need NSURLCache

You could use an actor instead of that static property and add the actor as a property in your network type
actor ResponseCache {
    private var cachedResponses: [NetworkResponse] = []

    func addResponse(_ response: NetworkResponse) {
        cachedResponses.append(response)
    }

    func clearResponses() {
        cachedResponses.removeAll()
    }

    func get(_ url: URL) -> NetworkResponse? {
        cachedResponses.first { $0.url == url }
    }
}

private extension NetworkRequestHandler {
    func response(for request: URLRequest) async -> NetworkResponse? {
        guard let url = request.url else { return nil }

        return await cachedResponses.get(url)
    }
}


i tired creating actor but got error when i try to implement in other method
Call to actor-isolated instance method 'response(for:)' in a synchronous nonisolated context

Well you need to use a Task (or .task in a View) or similar when accessing an asynchronous function.

i tried it also but it's like spinning in a circle
Cannot convert return expression of type 'Task<Bool, Never>' to return type 'Bool'

I don’t know what you are trying to do in your particular code but I get the impression you need to learn more about using async/await in swift

Just make your files as an actor like below I do:
actor SingletonWithStatic {
  private init() { }
  private var output = ""
  static let shared = SingletonWithStatic()

  func prepare(outputLine line: String) {
    output += line
    output += "\n"
  }

  func flushOutput() {
    print(output)
    output = ""
  }
}

Or you can silent your warning by making your static variable unsafe, but make sure you use that static variable in thread safe manner.
class SingletonWithStatic {
  private init() { }
  private var output = ""
  nonisolated(unsafe) static let shared = SingletonWithStatic()

  func prepare(outputLine line: String) {
    output += line
    output += "\n"
  }

  func flushOutput() {
    print(output)
    output = ""
  }
}

Or mark your class or struct as @MainActor
